# How to increase the resolution when running Selenium web driver test in Jenkins on VM

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, virtual-machine

Recently, I wrote C# test code using the selenium web driver. When running in mine PC, it work fine. However, when running in the Jenkins on VM, I meet some problems. And I try to print out the information as below,

```
IWebDriver driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();
Console.WriteLine(driver.Manage().Window.Size);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I got `{Width=1004, Height=748}`.

```
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
Console.WriteLine(driver.Manage().Window.Size);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I got `{Width=1040, Height=784}`.

```
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1280, 1024);
Console.WriteLine(driver.Manage().Window.Size);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I got `{Width=1040, Height=784}`.

The maximal window size is only `{Width=1040, Height=784}` which can not be increased.

So, when I take a screenshot, I will get picture like below,
[image: screenshot of my page]

How do I increase the window size or resolution? I have no idea about the issue. Please give me some suggestions to solve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Increase the Windows Resolution and then maximize your window. If your window doesn't support higher resolution, then you gotta change the monitor and install better drivers.

Comment: @GaurangShah Thanks for your suggestion. However, it runs on cloud VM. It seem not have display driver to setup?

Comment: did you tried screen resolution of VM? increase to high

Comment: @muraliselenium, I try to configure VM display resolution, however, it doesn't seem to be working. It still get {Width=1040, Height=784}

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remotely log in to the cloud machine and manually set the resolution for that user.

Answer (score 0):

stop jenkins service, re-run jenkins via cmd script:

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

my problem is fixed in my win7+jenkins.